# Spring @Service vs Object Service

Tags: java, spring

I have a question about `@Service` in spring, but i didn't find any response about it.

Situation :

I have a web application with `@RestController` using spring

Now for my service layer, I saw on some project two way of processing

- `@Service` on service class and `@Autowired` on controller class (Create a bean that is a singleton excepted if we change the scope)
- Create a object like a service

  MyService service = new MySerivce()

So my questions are :

- Create a object each time for each call of controller will not be a issue for memory ? If i create a load test (with Apache Jmeter) and send 1000 requests, it will create 1000 object my service so could be a problem no ?
- Create a singleton with `@Service` will not be a issue for memory but, how spring will handle 1000 requests on 1 seconds for example. Will he push requests on a sort of queue and execute one at a time ?
- What is the best practice for Service declaration and why ?

Thank in advance for any response

Comment: Why would messages sent to a singleton object need to be put in a queue? What do you think would prevent a singleton service from attending multiple concurrent requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of dependency injection (using annotations such as `@Autowired` and `@Service`, `@Component` etc.) is to let Spring manage instances of service classes for you, instead of manually creating an instance with `new MyService()` each time you need it.

Letting Spring manage service class instances (and other Spring beans) has a number of advantages. For example, it makes it a lot easier to replace a service with a different implementation; you only need to change the Spring configuration for that. Also, it makes it easy to inject a mock version of a service for unit testing. Replacing real services with mocks would be really hard if the class you are trying to test is directly instantiating a specific implementation of the service class using `new MyService()`.

> how spring will handle 1000 requests on 1 seconds for example. Will he push requests on a sort of queue and execute one at a time ?

No. Calling a method on a service is just like any other method call. There is no invisible queue and there is also no reason why that would be necessary, as long as the methods in the service are thread-safe.

> What is the best practice for Service declaration and why ?

When you use Spring, use Spring's dependency injection and never instantiate service classes using `new` in your code.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I understand now how spring really work about service. For me, i used @Service annotation, but on the project i am now, they use MyService service = new MyService().  So for you it will be a problem for the future ?

Comment: If Spring is being used on the project you are talking about, then using `MyService service = new MyService()` is most likely a mistake. But maybe there is some special reason for it, you'd have to ask the person who wrote it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Controller uses IOC mechanism like where Singleton objects are created, like in example you described @Service,

Application Server manages requests client, It uses thread pooling to handle request and generated or use same thread for request or response,
Spring applications are it self uses container mechanism where objects are created using @Service  and @Autowired annotations.

Comment: I will check the IOC mechanism right now. It could be usefull for the next . Thank for the reply

Answer (score 1):

- When ever we are using **`@Service`**, this means we are telling spring
  to create a object of that class and keep in **Spring container**, By
  default its Singleton. Wherever we are using `@Autowired` then spring
  handover that object to the Service/caller.
- Whenever we are calling 
   **`MyService service = new MySerivce()`**

   java
  creates new object of `MyService` every time. If that service called
  1000 times then **MyService** object will get created 1000 times, and Spring 
  has no control on this.

**Best Practice is** :
Use Spring @Service annotation to create object  and use annotation @Autowired to get that class object.

**Handling 1000 Requests**
Spring will not create 1000 new service object, it will use same service object (which is autowired) if object scope is Singleton which is default scope

but incase of Prototype, it  is same as creating a object with `new` keyword.
SO in this case it will create 1000 objects.
For handling huge requests we need to make thread safe, pooling separately, in this case Spring will use its container pooling which is not very efficient.